# Allow only specific classes within the class attribute in HTML purifier

Tags: php, html, htmlpurifier

I know that I can set the allowed tags and eventually attributes in [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) with something like:

`$cfg->set('HTML.Allowed', 'a[href|title],'b','em','i','strike');`

but how can I also disallow any attribute values that do not match certain predefined values?

For example I may want to allow the div + class tag:

`$cfg->set('HTML.Allowed', 'div[class],a[href|title],'b','em','i','strike');`

but only if the class is abc, def or xyz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [`Attr.AllowedClasses`](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#Attr.AllowedClasses). to limit only those classes you would like to allow.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it will set the allowed classes globally, for all elements. I cannot allow certain classes for `<DIV>`, and different classes for `<p>`, right?

Comment: @Rebecca from the manual it doesn't look like you can be more specific.